# Error while installation of twilio on python 2.7 windows 10 laptop

Tags: python-2.7, windows-10

I encountered following error which is as follows:

---

> build\temp.win32-2.7\Release_openssl.c(434) : fatal error C1083:
>   Cannot open include file: 'openssl/opensslv.h': No such file or
>   directory error: [Error 5] Access is denied:
>   'c:\users\admin\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-ajrfcv\cryptography-1.9\.eggs\cffi-1.10.0-py2.7-win32.egg\_cffi_backend.pyd'

---

I need help with this as to continue working.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You dont have enough access on the machine, are you the admin?. click yes if you get any administrator prompts

Comment: I had run cmd through as an administrator and current user active is administrator itself

Comment: you are doing pip install twilio?

Comment: I used easy_install twilio

Comment: download the wheel from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twilio , and install it with pip or easy_install

Comment: Any particular directory to move the file?

Comment: no , should work anywhere as long has you have permissions in that folder, if it shows the same error change the drive and try

Comment: I moved the downloaded file to Python27/Scripts still same error